# error when i use get_plugin_data() in a class and instance in main plugin file

Tags: php, wordpress, class, plugins

I create a class that managed my api call using curl.

I create a method that get me the version of my plugin but when i instance the class in the main file file of plugin get me an error.

ERROR:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> get_plugin_data().

the method :

```
$plugin_data = get_plugin_data( __FILE__ );
return $plugin_data['Version']."; wp:".wp_version_check()."; php:".phpversion();
```

the instance in the plugin class:

```
if(class_exists('API')){
   $this->api=new API();
}
```

i think that is because the path is not good for the main file

Answer (score 1):

The `get_plugin_data` function is not available at run time. You'll have to include the file containing the function declaration.

Try the following:

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    if( ! function_exists('get_plugin_data') ){
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
    }
    $plugin_data = get_plugin_data( __FILE__ );
}
```