# wp-admin/includes/plugin.php file not being automatically included

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use *get_plugin_data* function to retrieve my plugin version, however when i try to use it like:

`$version = get_plugin_data(__FILE__)['Version'];`

I get error: Error: Call to undefined function get_plugin_data()

After some research, i found out that file wp-admin/includes/plugin.php is not included on my local machine. But on our company server it is including this file automatically and therefor i can use it without problem (on the server).

My question is, if i have something wrong set up on my local machine, or what else might be causing wp-admin/includes/plugin.php not being loaded automatically, since it's WP core file.

My WP version is same as on the server 6.4.3 and i have no problem accessing the administration page of WP.

Comment: Does that answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71884287/error-when-i-use-get-plugin-data-in-a-class-and-instance-in-main-plugin-file

Comment: Is your site 100% the same as the server, plugins and everything? It is possible that your server has some additional plugins or settings that might cause that file to be included. But regardless, as Snuffy point out, there's no hard in guarding against it and conditionally including it using `require_once`

Comment: It does not answer my question since i am unable to use "core" WP functions that should be enabled globally.

Comment: "should be enabled globally" - Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_data/) I'm not seeing any promise that the function would be enabled globally, and there's even a comment at the bottom saying it isn't.

Comment: FWIW, WordPress is adding an autoloader for classes, and there was a discussion about adding a function autoloader however that was shelved for the time-being, although it is possible it could be added someday in the future.

Comment: @ChrisHaas That's comment from 2 years ago, under that is 2 months old comment about that it is indeed enabled by default so that confuses me even more.

Comment: After i compared WP core on my machine to what is on our server, i found out that indeed it is not automatically included, but our senior programmer actually uses some plugins which loads the 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php'. Since he was using them from the beginning and the file was loaded via the plugins, he thought that the function get_plugin_data is implemented by default.